# 404 (Not Found) Email Verification by userid and token issues in merstack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js

I sent email verification link from my Node.js backend to email, so when a user click on the verification link, they get verified.

The issue is that, users get 404 (Not Found) and undefined when they click on verification link from email. The generated link looks like:

```
// Email verification route
router.get('/verify/:userid/:verificationToken', userController.verifyEmail);

GET http://localhost:9000/api/verify?userid=6529898ffc439a5e00af99f6&verificationToken=undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

The `userid` is getting fetched tho, just the token is not getting passed in after been generated from backend.

**User SignUp Controller:**

```
userController.signup = async (req, res) => {
   try {
    const { fullName, email, password, referralCode } = req.body;
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
  
    if (existingUser) {
     return res.status(400).json({ error: "User with this email already exists" });
    }
  
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    const verificationToken = uuid.v4();
    console.log("User Token Generated:", verificationToken);
  
    const user = new User({
     fullName,
     email,
     password: hashedPassword,
     verificationToken,
     // role,
    });
  
    // Generate a unique referral code for the new user
    const referralLink = shortid.generate();
  
    user.referrerLink = referralLink;
  
    // Check if there's a referrer with the provided referral code
    if (referralCode) {
     const referrer = await User.findOne({ referralLink: referralCode });
  
     if (referrer) {
      user.referrer = referrer._id; // Track the referrer
      referrer.totalUsersReferred += 1; // Increment totalUsersReferred for the referrer
      await referrer.save();
     }
    }
  
    await user.save();
  
    // ... Send email verification ...
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
     host: "cryptokash.finance",
     port: 465,
     auth: {
      user: "courier@cryptokash.finance",
      pass: "123456789@2023!",
     },
    });
  
    transporter
     .verify()
     .then((res) => console.log(res, "transporter done"))
     .catch(console.error, "transporter error");
  
    // Send email verification link
    // const verificationLink = `${BASE_URL}/users/verify-email/${user.id}/${verificationToken}`;
    // Send email verification link
     const verificationLink = `${BASE_URL}/verify/${user.id}/${encodeURIComponent(verificationToken)}`;
  
  
    const mailOptions = {
     from: EMAIL_USERNAME,
     to: user.email,
     subject: "Email Verification - PackPushers",
     html: `Click the following link to verify your email: <a href="${verificationLink}">${verificationLink}</a>`,
    };
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  
    res.json({
     message: "User registered successfully. Please check your email for verification.",
    });
   } catch (err) {
    console.log(err, "-------");
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error" });
   }
  };
```

**Email verification controller**

```
userController.verifyEmail = async (req, res) => {
  // Validate userId and token
  try {
    const { userid, verificationToken } = req.query;

    // Check if the userId is valid
    if (!userId || typeof userId !== 'string') {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid user ID.' });
    }

    // Check if the token is valid
    if (!verificationToken || typeof verificationToken !== 'string') {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid token.' });
    }

    // Find the user by userId
    const user = await User.findById(userId);

    // Check if the user exists
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found.' });
    }

    // Check if the user's verification token matches the token from the URL
    if (user.verificationToken !== verificationToken) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid token. Please check your email for the correct verification link.' });
    }

    // Mark the user as verified in the database
    user.isVerified = true;
    user.verificationToken = undefined; // Optionally, you can clear the verification token
    await user.save();

    res.json({ message: 'Email verification successful.' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Server error' });
  }
};
```

**How I consume The APIs From Frontend**

```
"use client"

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
// import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation';
import Navbar from "@/components/ui/navbar";
import Footer from "@/components/ui/footer";


const VerifyEmail = () => {
  // const router = useRouter();
const params = useParams()

  // const { userid, verificationToken } = router.query;
  const { userid, verificationToken } = params
  console.log(userid,verificationToken,'-----++')

  const [message, setMessage] = useState("Verifying...");

  useEffect(() => {
    const verifyEmail = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/api/verify?userid=${userid}&verificationToken=${verificationToken}`);

        if (response.data.success) {
          setMessage("Email verification successful!");
        } else {
          setMessage("Email verification failed.");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        setMessage("Email verification failed. Please try again later.");
      }
    };

    verifyEmail();
  }, [userid, verificationToken]);

  return (
    <>
    <Navbar/>
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen">
      <div className="bg-white p-8 shadow-md rounded-lg">
        <h1 className="text-3xl font-semibold mb-4">{message}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <Footer/>
    </>
  );
};

export default VerifyEmail;
```

Comment: What is `GET http://localhost:9000/api/verify?userid=6529898ffc439a5e00af99f6&verificationToken=undefined 404 (Not Found)` in your first code block? Is that what you are sending to the user as a verification link?

Comment: This is the verification link:  
const verificationLink = `${BASE_URL}/verify/${user.id}/${encodeURIComponent(verificationToken)}`;

It was on that I posted earlier.

Comment: That is not what you are actually sending to the user though. You have to find where the problem is. Is the Token not generated properly in the first place and the user is receiving an incorrect token, or is it generate properly and submitted properly , but not retrieved properly when you try to verify it

Comment: the token is genrated proprely: 

User Token Generated: ```254d7991-6688-4ff4-82cf-16383743cec7```

Comment: Good, but thats still not the link, thats the token. The link you say the user gets is this ` http://localhost:9000/api/verify?userid=6529898ffc439a5e00af99f6&verificationToken=undefined 404 (Not Found)` which has no token. Is the user getting the token in their email?

Comment: Users gets token in the email like so:

```http://localhost:3000/verify/6529c9cc77a8bb8873583fb9/254d7991-6688-4ff4-82cf-16383743cec7```

The BASE url is:

```BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000```
Note that the API base URL is:

```http://localhost:9000```

Could there be mix up there?

Comment: Yes quite possibly. Often your front end will be served from port 3000 and the api from another port, say 9000 and the dev server will proxy calls to the api on 9000 during development. You should try using localhost:9000, and manually test the link from your browser. Also note that the link mention in the last comment is different to the one in your first code block. The one you show in comment just above looks correct for the route path, the one in the question doesnt (look at the params).